# Adobe Encoder Desyncs Video/Audio (MTS to MP4)

Tags: encoding, adobe, transcoding, sync, adobe-media-encoder

I've been trying to transcode an MTS (recorded on a Panasonic) to MP4 with Adobe Media Encoder. The audio/video has consistently gone out of sync. I've matched the source, gone over all the settings, and restarted both computer and program, but it hasn't seemed to work.

I then turned to other encoders with different results. Out of all of the ones I tried, [Wondershare Free Video Converter](https://videoconverter.wondershare.com/free-video-converter.html) seemed to work the best: it didn't desync the audio/video, and it didn't interpolate the video. Using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), I tried to recreate all the parameters from Wondershare to Encoder, but the audio/video STILL go out of sync.

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below are the specs of the MTS (original), Wonder Share (no sync issues), and Encoder (-500ms audio/video desync).

**MTS** (original)

```
General 
ID : 1 (0x1) 
Complete name : E:\2019\001.MTS 
Format : BDAV 
Format/Info : Blu-ray Video 
File size : 1.94 GiB 
Duration : 23 min 52 s 
Overall bit rate mode : Variable 
Overall bit rate : 11.6 Mb/s 
Maximum Overall bit rate : 18.0 Mb/s 
Recorded date : 2019-01-18 14:24:17-05:00 
Writing application : Panasonic 

Video 
ID : 4113 (0x1011) 
Menu ID : 1 (0x1) 
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : High@L4 
Format settings : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames 
Format settings, CABAC : Yes 
Format settings, Reference frames : 2 frames 
Format settings, GOP : M=3, N=15 
Codec ID : 27 
Duration : 23 min 52 s 
Bit rate mode : Variable 
Bit rate : 10.8 Mb/s 
Maximum bit rate : 16.8 Mb/s 
Width : 1 920 pixels 
Height : 1 080 pixels 
Display aspect ratio : 16:9 
Frame rate : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS 
Color space : YUV 
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 
Bit depth : 8 bits 
Scan type : Interlaced 
Scan type, store method : Separated fields 
Scan order : Top Field First 
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.173 
Stream size : 1.79 GiB (93%) 

Audio 
ID : 4352 (0x1100) 
Menu ID : 1 (0x1) 
Format : AC-3 
Format/Info : Audio Coding 3 
Commercial name : Dolby Digital 
Codec ID : 129 
Duration : 23 min 52 s 
Bit rate mode : Constant 
Bit rate : 384 kb/s 
Channel(s) : 6 channels 
Channel layout : L R C LFE Ls Rs 
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz 
Frame rate : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF) 
Compression mode : Lossy 
Delay relative to video : -434 ms 
Stream size : 65.6 MiB (3%) 
Service kind : Complete Main 

Text 
ID : 4608 (0x1200) 
Menu ID : 1 (0x1) 
Format : PGS 
Codec ID : 144 
Duration : 23 min 52 s
```

**Wondershare** (no sync issues)

```
General 
Complete name : C:\Users\elm201\Desktop\Wondershare\Converted\001_H.264_Prog_6mbps_AAC.mp4 
Format : MPEG-4 
Format profile : Base Media / Version 2 
Codec ID : mp42 (mp42) 
File size : 172 MiB 
Duration : 3 min 54 s 
Overall bit rate : 6 143 kb/s 
Codirector : codirector 
Production studio : studio 
ContentType : Unknown Type 
Encoded date : UTC 2019-11-15 14:08:02 
Tagged date : UTC 2019-11-15 14:08:02 

Video 
ID : 1 
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : Main@L4.1 
Format settings : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames 
Format settings, CABAC : Yes 
Format settings, Reference frames : 2 frames 
Format settings, GOP : M=3, N=25 
Muxing mode : Container profile=Baseline@3.0 
Codec ID : avc1 
Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding 
Duration : 3 min 54 s 
Bit rate : 6 008 kb/s 
Width : 1 920 pixels 
Height : 1 080 pixels 
Display aspect ratio : 16:9 
Frame rate mode : Constant 
Frame rate : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS 
Color space : YUV 
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 
Bit depth : 8 bits 
Scan type : Progressive 
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.097 
Stream size : 168 MiB (98%) 
Language : English 
Codec configuration box : avcC 

Audio 
ID : 2 
Format : AAC LC 
Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity 
Codec ID : mp4a-40-2 
Duration : 3 min 54 s 
Bit rate mode : Constant 
Bit rate : 128 kb/s 
Channel(s) : 2 channels 
Channel layout : L R 
Sampling rate : 44.1 kHz 
Frame rate : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF) 
Compression mode : Lossy 
Stream size : 3.57 MiB (2%) 
Title : Stereo 
Language : English 
Default : Yes 
Alternate group : 1
```

**Encoder** (-500ms off)

```
General 
Complete name : C:\Users\elm201\Desktop\Encoder\001_Progressive_6mbps_Constant.mp4 
Format : MPEG-4 
Format profile : Base Media / Version 2 
Codec ID : mp42 (mp42/mp41) 
File size : 168 MiB 
Duration : 3 min 49 s 
Overall bit rate mode : Variable 
Overall bit rate : 6 139 kb/s 
Encoded date : UTC 2019-11-15 14:51:40 
Tagged date : UTC 2019-11-15 14:53:00 
TIM : 00:20:02:17 
TSC : 30000 
TSZ : 1001 

Video 
ID : 1 
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : Main@L4.1 
Format settings : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames 
Format settings, CABAC : Yes 
Format settings, Reference frames : 4 frames 
Format settings, GOP : M=4, N=29 
Codec ID : avc1 
Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding 
Duration : 3 min 49 s 
Bit rate : 6 009 kb/s 
Width : 1 920 pixels 
Height : 1 080 pixels 
Display aspect ratio : 16:9 
Frame rate mode : Constant 
Frame rate : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS 
Color space : YUV 
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 
Bit depth : 8 bits 
Scan type : Progressive 
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.097 
Stream size : 164 MiB (98%) 
Language : English 
Encoded date : UTC 2019-11-15 14:51:40 
Tagged date : UTC 2019-11-15 14:51:40 
Color range : Limited 
Color primaries : BT.709 
Transfer characteristics : BT.709 
Matrix coefficients : BT.709 
Codec configuration box : avcC 

Audio 
ID : 2 
Format : AAC LC 
Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity 
Codec ID : mp4a-40-2 
Duration : 3 min 49 s 
Source duration : 3 min 49 s 
Bit rate mode : Variable 
Bit rate : 126 kb/s 
Maximum bit rate : 206 kb/s 
Channel(s) : 2 channels 
Channel layout : L R 
Sampling rate : 44.1 kHz 
Frame rate : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF) 
Compression mode : Lossy 
Stream size : 3.43 MiB (2%) 
Source stream size : 3.43 MiB (2%) 
Language : English 
Encoded date : UTC 2019-11-15 14:51:40 
Tagged date : UTC 2019-11-15 14:51:40
```